# Android lib/api to query, which Manifest.permission.XXXX are currently missing?

Tags: android, security, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am maintaining two android developper tools [intent-intercept](https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept/)
and [ContentProviderHelper](https://github.com/k3b/ContentProviderHelper/)
that declare as many required permessions as possible to work with as many apis (Intents or Contentproviders) as possible.

If i want to use target-api android-6.0 (M) and newer i have to implement an api to ask os/user to grant permission for a certain 
api call.

And that is my problem: i donot know in advance which api-call(Intents or Contentproviders) require which permission.

As developper tools the app-s should work with any api.

How can I solve this? Is there a api/lib that tells me which Manifest.permission.XXXX are neccessary to invoke Intents or Contentprovider
or why last call failed?

Do i have to ask for all permissions even if they are not required?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a api/lib that tells me which Manifest.permission.XXXX are neccessary to invoke Intents or Contentprovider

No.

> or why last call failed?

Catch the `SecurityException`, then examine the message of the `SecurityException` and see if it contains the name of a `dangerous` permission.